# What are the cool downs for swapping skill/runes?

Tags: diablo-iii

D3 lacks the skill tree of D2, a character seems to be able to unlock all skills available to their class.

Is the cool down for swapping the skills/runes consistent across all classes and how long is this cool down?

Comment: They don't seem to be able - they are :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [combat skills](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/combat-skills) section of Blizzard's online game guide, the cooldowns for swapping skills are:

> - Normal: 5 seconds
> - Nightmare: 10 seconds
> - Hell: 15 seconds
> - Inferno: 2 minutes

These cooldowns only apply if you switch skills outside of town. You may freely switch skills in town with no cooldown.

Comment: Just to add, switching skills resets your Nephalem Valor buff to 0. http://www.diablowiki.net/Nephalem_Valor

Answer (score 5):

There is a 5 second CD on Normal difficulty unless you are in a town (no CD at all).

- Normal: 5s
- Nightmare: 10s

On higher difficulties the cooldown will be even longer.